# Custom post type page for authors

Tags: custom-post-types

I've got 30+ users and several custom post types.

- Classes
- Downloads
- Parties
- Events
- etc

At the moment, I'm using `author.php` to display all these custom posts for **that** user, each post type in a loop, each hidden in a tab format.

`http://www.websites.com/members/steve`

I've been asked if there's a way of having each post type on it's on URL

`http://www.websites.com/members/steve/classes`

`http://www.websites.com/members/jean/parties`

`http://www.websites.com/members/peter/events`

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be done with URLs in WordPress... unfortunately not too easily a lot of the time. :)

It will probably be overkill to construct completely custom rewrite rules for that. Since you only have one extra variable/variation to the template it seems like handling it via endpoint (see [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)) might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, do you have any examples of endpoints in use? My research so far has only lead me to the core function, and not a custom one

Comment: @AndrewLazarus linked Codex documentation has link to pretty extensive blog post on endpoints